# PHP Wrong Date Format When Using Under Condition

Tags: php, date, datetime

This is the function which is working fine for my site giving correct date format:

```
function mydate($date){
$date1=date_create($date); $date=date_format($date1,"l, F j, Y"); 
return $date;
}
```

But when I use the same function with some conditional logic it produce incorrect date format:

```
function mydate($date)
{
   if($date=='--' || $date =''){return ' Not Available';}
else{ $date1=date_create($date); return date_format($date1,"l, F j, Y"); }
}
```

Whats wrong I am doing ?

The function always giving output of today.

Comment: check this line **if($date=='--' || $date=''){return ' Not Available';}** 
and replace this condition $date='' with $date == ''

Comment: $date1 what is use of this variable ? is it $date ?

Comment: @rahuI_m  just used $date1 to create_date [date_create($date)] and return the $date1 with date_format

Comment: Check here its [working](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cb9df0b6eec2d5af36f509db35419359f31633ca)

Comment: Thank You Very Much !! It seems that $date= was actual culprit. After clearing the cache the function is now working fine !! Great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem is here:**

> `$date=''`, In your conditional statement you are not just checking you are initializing a value that's why it will always return `Not Available`

If you assign `$date=''` then `date_create($date);` this will return current date and then current date will be returned in this format `l, F j, Y`

**Change this to:**

```
function mydate($date){
if($date=='--' || $date=''){return ' Not Available';}
else{ $date1=date_create($date); return date_format($date1,"l, F j, Y"); }
}
```

**This:**

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/786063)

```
function mydate($date){
if($date=='--' || $date==''){return ' Not Available';}
else{ $date1=date_create($date); return date_format($date1,"l, F j, Y"); }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for Your correction , BUT after correcting '=' to '==' the problem still remains same. The function is giving output of today.

Comment: @AtaiRabby can you tell me the problem you are getting? can you share the input of `$date`?

Comment: Yes. Please visit here http://yscholar.com/ and you will see the output (under each output I have provided the original date)

Comment: @AtaiRabby Try this https://eval.in/786063 Hope this will help you out..

Comment: Yes, I checked that. Thank You Very Much !! It seems that $date= was actual culprit. After clearing the cache the function is now working fine !! Great :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143255/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-atai-rabby).